# Writing Firebase functions in languages other than JS

Tags: firebase, function, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, oncreate

I want to implement Firebase's Firestore Functions like onCreate or onUpdate but I would like to know if it actually supports other programming languages other than JavaScript or TypeScript for such purposes? I've done some research, most people say Firebase now supports other languages but I think they're confused with GCP (Google's Cloud Platform) which is a different service suite. Also I can't find any tutorial related to implementing Firestore Functions in other languages.

If Firestore has not really support other languages yet, does Firebase Admin SDK has some workaround that's similar to Function's onCreate?

Thanks!

Comment: The Cloud Firestore triggers seem to still be in beta. They might go for JS/TS first since it is so widespread and events and asynchronisity are built into the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does support multiple languages such as Python, Java, Go.
The question has already been answered on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62760664/firebase-multi-programming-language-suppport#:%7E:text=When%20deploying%20your%20Cloud%20Functions,JavaScript%20and%20TypeScript%20on%20Node.).

You can refer to the official Firecasts playlist on how the setup on multiple languages [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLnJVX_0zbKytptZGugPIbJR).